# postgres function : copy from txt file to database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.4

I found below function which copy data from csv to Postgres, it also creates table dynamically from csv, I want similar function but it should do for text files.

I am not from development background and I have to load a txt file to Postgres table dynamically.

is it possible to make below function to work with txt files?

```
create or replace function public.load_csv_file
(
target_table text,
csv_path text,
col_count integer
)

returns void as $$

declare

iter integer; -- dummy integer to iterate columns with
col text; -- variable to keep the column name at each iteration
col_first text; -- first column name, e.g., top left corner on a csv file or     spreadsheet

begin
set schema 'public';

create table insert_from_csv ();

-- add just enough number of columns
for iter in 1..col_count
loop
    execute format('alter table insert_from_csv add column col_%s text;', iter);
end loop;

-- copy the data from csv file
execute format('copy insert_from_csv from %L with delimiter '','' quote ''"'' csv ', csv_path);

iter := 1;
col_first := (select col_1 from insert_from_csv limit 1);

-- update the column names based on the first row which has the column names
for col in execute format('select unnest(string_to_array(trim(temp_table::text, ''()''), '','')) from temp_table where col_1 = %L', col_first)
loop
    execute format('alter table insert_from_csv rename column col_%s to %s', iter, col);
    iter := iter + 1;
end loop;

-- delete the columns row
execute format('delete from insert_from_csv where %s = %L', col_first, col_first);

-- change the temp table name to the name given as parameter, if not blank
if length(target_table) > 0 then
    execute format('alter table insert_from_csv rename to %I', target_table);
end if;

end;

$$ language plpgsql;
```

Any help from experts would help me a lot.

Comment: Probably changing the delimiter and format will suffice.  What's the column separator of your text file?

Comment: A CSV file *is* a text file. What is your *question*?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter-When i tried to load from csv file got - org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "User"
  Where: PL/pgSQL function load_csv_file(text,text,integer) line 29 at EXECUTE
CSV File:
User,Customer Risk,Declined Reason,Application Status,Date,Metrics,# of Applications,# of High Risk Applications
amcconnell7,Lowest,Not declined,Initiated,11-May-2017,,2,
amcconnell7,Lowest,Not declined,Initiated,12-May-2017,,1,
amcconnell7,Lowest,Not declined,Initiated,15-May-2017,,1,

To avoid any character issue i was thinking if i can use txt instead of csv

Comment: Postgres has some issue with first letter of first column, if it is upper case then it is giving error and works well with small letter. Does any one know why?

Comment: Yes, we all know why. Postgres's table and column names are case-insensitive, **unless** they are quoted (using double quotes). Your `%L` and `%I` effectively put the identifiers in quotes.

Comment: Hi Joop, Thanks for looking into it.
i tried as per your comment, changed below 
execute format('alter table insert_from_csv rename column col_%s to %s ', iter, col); 
to
execute format('alter table insert_from_csv rename column col_%L to %I ', iter, col);
And got below error:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "'1'"
  Where: PL/pgSQL function load_csv_file(text,text,integer) line 29 at EXECUTE

Am i doing correct changes?

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has some issue with first letter of first column, if it is upper case then it is giving error and works well with small letter.

Thanks erwin & michel for responding.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to modify the function, which will replace any spaces with '_' and rename column names to lower case.

```
create or replace function load_csv_file
(
target_table text,
csv_path text,
col_count integer
)

returns void 
SECURITY DEFINER
as $$

declare

iter integer; -- dummy integer to iterate columns with
col text; -- variable to keep the column name at each iteration
col_first text; -- first column name, e.g., top left corner on a csv file or     spreadsheet

begin
set schema 'test';

create table insert_from_csv ();

-- add just enough number of columns
for iter in 1..col_count
loop
execute format('alter table insert_from_csv add column col_%s text;', iter);
end loop;

-- copy the data from csv file
execute format('copy insert_from_csv from %L delimiter '','' csv ',     csv_path);

iter := 1;
col_first := (select col_1 from insert_from_csv limit 1);

-- update the column names based on the first row which has the column names
for col in execute format('select unnest(string_to_array(lower(replace(trim(insert_from_csv::text, ''()''),'' '',''_'')), '','')) from insert_from_csv where col_1 = %L', col_first)
loop
execute format('alter table insert_from_csv rename column col_%s to %s', iter, col);
iter := iter + 1;
end loop;

-- delete the columns row
execute format('delete from insert_from_csv where %I = %L', col_first, col_first);

-- change the temp table name to the name given as parameter, if not blank
if length(target_table) > 0 then
execute format('alter table insert_from_csv rename to %I', target_table);
end if;

end;

$$ language plpgsql;
```